# Getting all matches for a regexp on clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I'm trying to parse an HTML file and get all href's inside it.

So far, the code I'm using is:

```
(map 
   #(println (str "Match: " %)) 
   (re-find #"(?sm)href=\"([a-zA-Z.:/]+)\"" str_response))
```

str_response being the string with the HTML code inside it. According to my basic understanding of Clojure, that code should print a list of matches, but so far, no luck.
It doens't crash, but it doens't match anything either.
I've tried using `re-seq` instead of `re-find`, but with no luck. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: if you include the value of str_response in your question I can help with the regex,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really looks like an HTML scraping problem in which case, I would advise using [enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive).

Something like this should work

```
(ns test.foo
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]))

(let [url (html/html-resource
           (java.net.URL. "http://www.nytimes.com"))]
  (map #(-> % :attrs :href) (html/select url [:a])))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems to be the most "elegant" one.

Answer (score 4):

it is generally though that [you cannot parse html with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/90801) (entertaining answer), though just finding all occurances of one tag should be dooable.

once you figure out the proper regex `re-seq` is the function you want to use:

```
user> (re-find #"aa" "aalkjkljaa")
"aa"
user> (re-seq #"aa" "aalkjkljaa")
("aa" "aa")
```

this is not crashing for you because re-find is returning nil which map is interpreting as an empty list and doing nothing

Comment: Well... not so doable if you wanted to do it right. Want to exclude non-XML text quoted as CDATA? Want to exclude tags which belong to a different namespace? Etc.

Comment: you are completely correct: I highly recommend the linked answer on this topic :) "the center cannot hold..."

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. Perhaps`str_response`is the suspect. The following works with http://google.com with your regex:

```
(let [str_response (slurp "http://google.com")]
  (map #(println (str "Match: " %)) 
   (re-seq #"(?sm)href=\"([a-zA-Z.:/]+)\"" str_response))
```

Note `ref-find` also works though it only returns one match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for some reason, that code inside my project didn't print anything, I've decided to go with Julien's solution anyways. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: You're welcome. As far as parsing html is concerned Chris Grand's enlive is the way to go.